# WD my cloud 4th is Super Slow

Tags: networking, mac, performance

I am using a WD my cloud 4Tb and I have read other posts about users complaining about getting only 10Mb per second.  My problem is that I am getting about 100kb/s to transfer a 125gb iPhoto library.  Estimated time is 11 days to transfer this file.  This is unacceptable.

On the back of the WD cloud I am getting a solid green light and from what I read this means that I am on a gigabyte network.  I have mac book pro running Mac OS Mavericks.

I have tried 4 different cables and turned off my router firewall.  I don't run anti-virus nor any firewall on the mac.

Other things I have checked: direct connection to both router and WD cloud device.  Tried wireless but it is even slower.

Previously I was able to transfer a 55Gb iPhoto library in 14 hours which I felt was acceptable.  I figured it would take approximately double the time to transfer the 125gb file but 11 days is ridiculous.  Any other suggestions?  Anything else I can check (how to check it) what is the bottle neck?

Comment: Thank you @Nevin Williams,                                                        That was such great detail.  I believe I know what happened.  With a large file transfer with around 10,000 folders it takes a long time to set up all the folders.  For the first hour the transfer was going super slow then after that it was able to transfer it over in about 4 hours.  I don't know why it takes so long to transfer iPhoto library even with all the folders (still just bits).  There are formatting issues I have to take care of now.  I did use some of my home cables but i also tried manufacture ones.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your **MyCloud** device directly to your MacBook via Ethernet, with no router or other device in between. Under the `Sharing` System Preference Pane, enable `Internet Sharing`.  In the ***"Share your connection from"*** pull-down, select `Wi-Fi`.  In the box below ***'To Computers using'***, check `Ethernet`.  This will give your `MyCloud` a DHCP address to work with your Ethernet interface.

You should now be able to connect to your `MyCloud` in the usual way.

Begin a large file transfer as a test.

Open `Terminal.app`, in `/Applications/Utilities/`.

To see with what link speed your `MyCloud` has connected to your Macbook, do:

`ifconfig en0` or perhaps `ifconfig en2` if using Thunderbolt.   This will give an interface description like:

```
[Nevins-Mac-mini:~] nevin% ifconfig en0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether 3c:07:54:5c:ab:ad 
    inet6 fe80::3e07:54ff:fe5c:abad%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.2.122 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex,flow-control>)
    status: active
[Nevins-Mac-mini:~] nevin%
```

The `status: active` line means I'm looking at a connected interface, and the `media:` line above it means I've got a Gigabit connection that's full-duplex and supports flow-control.

With a large file-transfer in progress, look at traffic statistics with `netstat`:

```
[Nevins-Mac-mini:~] nevin% netstat -vI en0 8
                     input          (en0)           output
            packets  errs      bytes    packets  errs      bytes colls
03:36:07       3174     0     305928       6083     0    9171948     0
03:36:15       3085     0     297366       6145     0    9268910     0
03:36:23       3166     0     305142       6071     0    9155228     0
```

(The trailing 8 tells `netstat` to take 8 second samples, which means the 'bytes' column is actually a bits/sec average)

This shows I was sending data at 9 Mb/sec, which is about right for my network connection, with no link-level errors.

I don't know what the max throughput should be for your equipment, but even if you were only getting 10% of a Gigabit/sec, 125 Gigabytes = 1000 Gigabits.  At just 0.1 Gb/s, that would be 10,000 seconds, or just under 3 hours.

Are your cables home-made, by chance?